# Job Scheduler with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Every 30 minutes their server generates an XML file with product inside, so my site every half hour would make a request to the URL given to me, their server will generate the XML list updated and will importarselo automatically to update our site.

Does anyone have an idea of how you can implement in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Quartz.NET is a full-featured, open source job scheduling system that can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems.

Comment: Quartz.NET seems overkill for just saving a file to disk from an URL every half an hour. :)

Comment: ok I solved it all with the library that I have suggested above

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could [simulate a Windows Service using ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx) to download and import the XML at scheduled intervals.  Otherwise, use a dedicated scheduler like [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) (already mentioned by Mendy), or build your own Windows Service, or run an import script using Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: I'd recommend the Task Scheduler for this. There's no need to complicate things by involving ASP in the update mechanism - especially since that would somehow probably require ASP to have write access to files.