# Background task / job / process, in asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, backgroundworker, observers

I don't know where to start or what to use to solve this 2 problems:

1. I have a User model and a Event model (football match, karts race, etc). And I want that when a user creates a new Event send and email to other users.
2. I need "something" that checks let's say every 15 minutes, delete all the Events that are already over (Example: Events from yesterday) from the database.

I know that in Ruby on Rails, there are Observers and Background Workers, there is something like that in MVC3 ? or there are other ways of accomplish that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [scheduled task or windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811653/scheduled-task-or-windows-service)

Comment: Yeah, that the job for a windows service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those kind of tasks are better suited to be done from a separate process such as a Windows service. You should [avoid using background tasks](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) in your web applications.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) as a robust solution because of being full-featured, open source job scheduling system that can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems.

More Info: [Job Scheduler with asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628214/job-scheduler-with-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

It's true that there are risks. But sometimes we have to take this option, especially when we are on a tight schedule to implement a job queue. If you are not familier with windows services, you need to learn about those things.

Following worked for me, (.NET 4.5.2). Once I invoke `InitiateLongRunningProcess` controller, it initiate a longrunning process and return to view without waiting for the longrunning job.

```
public ActionResult InitiateLongRunningProcess(Emails emails)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => LongRunningProcessAsync(emails.Email));
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return View(user);
}
```

Read this great article from Hanselman [HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late but you should consider lookint at http://hangfire.io/. Its an amazing library and provides a full fletched UI to manage jobs :)